# Creating xaml element in code-behind using gong dragdrop

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop

I am fairly new to C#. This may be a fairly straight forward question, but I couldn't find any example about this. I am just wondering if there is any way when I create XAML element in the code-behind file(`.xaml.cs`), I can use other open source library(such as `GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop`) property in the element?

An example will be as following, can I create the following XAML code in the code-behind(`.xaml.cs`) file?

```
<...
xmlns:dd="urn:gong-wpf-dragdrop"
...
>
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" />
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally need to know how to set values for ***AttachedProperties*** from code behind. Below code should help for your case,

```
listBox.SetValue(GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.DragDrop.IsDragSourceProperty, true);
listBox.SetValue(GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.DragDrop.IsDropTargetProperty, true);
```

If you want to be type safe, you can set the same like this,

```
GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.DragDrop.SetIsDragSource(listBox, true);
GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.DragDrop.SetIsDropTarget(listBox, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have any recommendation of book for learning WPF? This seems to be a very basic WPF technique...